# How do I make a floating image float to the top right of a div?

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of divs that are generated dynamically.  When the text is long, it will wrap.  Which is fine, but the floating delete icon floats to the bottom.

A few things to note before looking at the code.  The width in the example is static, but in my use it's defined by the container.  I would rather not use absolute positioning, but will as last resort.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about (http://jsfiddle.net/3FYv8/1/)

```
<div class="deletableGroup">Marketing Department
    <img title="delete" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dryicons/simplistica/16/delete-icon.png"/>
</div>
<div class="deletableGroup">Sales
    <img title="delete" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dryicons/simplistica/16/delete-icon.png"/>
</div>
```

css:

```
.deletableGroup img {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
}
.deletableGroup {
    width: 125px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: solid 2px lightskyblue;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quickest way to solve this problem would be to move the `<img>` before the text...

```
<div class="deletableGroup">
    <img title="delete" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dryicons/simplistica/16/delete-icon.png" />
Marketing Department
</div>
```

[Here is an updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/jQB9Q/)

Comment: Perfect (so simple), I'll accept this as the answer when the SO timer allows me to.

Comment: @Smeegs: Yeah, it's nice when you get a simple fix... and although it would be personal preference, adding `vertical-align:top;` to `.deletableGroup` looks nicer, IMO

Comment: @Smeegs: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/jQB9Q/1/), what browser you have? Might require you to wrap them all in a parent div perhaps (ignore the other style changes, I got carried away playing)

Answer (score 2):

Just add this :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="deletableGroup">
    <img title="delete" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dryicons/simplistica/16/delete-icon.png"/>
    Marketing Department    
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.deletableGroup img{
    float:right;    
}
```

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/3FYv8/2/

Comment: OP already has that CSS, you can't just suggest what they already have!

Comment: I had that already, what you did that works is what @musefan suggested, you moved the image before the text.

Comment: @Smeegs : Yeah, i tried updating ur fiddle. Dint see the particular css initially and i added it thinking it was not there.. :).. But glad ur prob is solved.. cheers

Comment: @musefan : Yep, i missed that initially..;)